# Update record using loadash - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have below method to delete an element from object array of my ReactJS script using 'loadash'. How can add another method for updating the same an object (UPDATE_TICKET) with new values ?

```
 case ActionTypes.DELETE_TICKET:
  _.remove(_tickets, ticket => (action.id === ticket.id));
 TicketStore.emitChange();
```

Sample data:

```
"tickets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test1",
      "desc": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test2",
      "desc": "test2"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please add an example of data, and expected result.

Comment: @OriDrori Sample data added; thanks!

Comment: What should be the result after the update?

Comment: BTW - are you using FLUX? If so prefer, reject to remove. The latter mutates the object, which might cause problems.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes, I use FLUX

Comment: What should be the result after the update?